# About Robots. txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

What if I leave the user agent empty in the robots.txt file.

It is basically like that:
User-agent: *

Disallow: /specific page

**But What if it is like:**

**User-agent**:

Disallow: /specific page

Comment: Why would you actively want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to allow *no* user agents?

Comment: It would be ignored https://technicalseo.com/tools/robots-txt/, ie, the page would still be crawled by any bots

Answer (score 0):

User-agent: * Specifies instructions for all robots of all search engines simultaneously

Or if you want to specify for a specific search engine, use
User-agent: Googlebot

So if you do not specify an asterisk, there is a chance that search bots will not understand what the designations after